# Embed json file within .exe file

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to publish my console application into 1 exe file. I have managed to embed the dll files into the exe file by adding to the csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
      <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However I still need my file extractConfig.json in the same space as the exe file as well or else it will not run. How can I embed this file into the exe as well?

It is currently getting published like so:

[image]

But I need it so it is just the exe file

Comment: I dont get it, is it a config file? Then why do you want to embed it? It is a static configuration, then create a class with constants. It is a dynamic configuration? Then it is ok how it is

Comment: It is a config file which states things such as where the csv file which the application creates is exported to, and the connection string for connecting to the database it uses so without this, it will not work which is why I need it within the exe

Comment: And if you change the configuration parameters (like the location of the folder or the database server)  you need to recompile exe... that's why config files are distributed as you are doing now, and it's ok

Comment: it won't be changed. I need it as a single file so it's not okay as it is now

Comment: As I already stated: If it does not change use constants in your code not a config file. Your usage of a config file is a misconception

Comment: Or even better: Use environment variables. This way you don't keep sensitive information within your code and still have only the exe file.

Comment: the json file was how I had been asked to do it which is why it's been done this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with the people I am working with and have gone with the suggestion from @SirOneOfMany and I am now using constants rather than the json file which easily allows me to just have the 1 exe file.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

#### Create the config if it does not exist

When the program starts you check if the config file exist. If not, you create it. You could create this file from a default configuration object that you serialize, or include the configuration file as a string resource or some other way. I would also consider placing this file in the localappdata folder instead, since you might not have write access to the folder of the .exe file.

#### Exclude the configuration file from the package

You can add the ExcludeFromSingleFile option for the config file so that it is not included in the single .exe file. This will obviously require you to deploy multiple files.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="extractConfig.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```